# how to have more texture slots in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

i'm learning opengl, when i was using textures i noticed that slots are limited to 31, is there any way to use images so that slots are not limited, or at least have more slots? and I also found it a little useless to use locShader in the class, since it doesn't use any private variables to auto-allocate, and I need to provide the slot

here is the code for texture.h:

```cpp
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <std/std_image.h>
#include <Shader.h>

class Texture{
    public:
        Texture(const char *file, GLenum repeat, GLenum buffer, GLenum slot){
            glActiveTexture(slot);
            glGenTextures(1, &ID);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);

            stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
            int imgWidth, imgHeight, nrChannels;
            unsigned char *data=stbi_load(file, &imgWidth, &imgHeight, &nrChannels, 0);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, repeat);  
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, repeat);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, buffer);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, buffer);
            
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        void alocShader(Shader &shader, const char *Loc, GLuint id){
            GLuint texUni=glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), Loc);
            glUseProgram(shader.getID());
            glUniform1i(texUni, id);
        }
        void bind(){
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
        }
        void unbind(){
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
        void del(){
            glDeleteTextures(1, &ID);
        }
    private:
        GLuint ID;
};

#endif
```

Comment: If your shader only has a single texture uniform, then a single slot is enough. You can bind different textures to it dynamically.

Comment: What are you doing that you need to have more than 30 textures accessible by a single shader stage in the same rendering command? Textures don't permanently live in binding slots.

Comment: I think it's a hardware limitation. Just replace the texture with another one.

Comment: I'm new to opengl, and I came from apis that let me put as many textures as I want, and I've never moved mt with shader, but if you can replace one with the other in rendering, it's all right, and in this case I'll make a mini 2d project with scenery 3d, a nice 2.5d

Comment: @JoséAntônio: Those APIs don't let you have as many textures as you want used by a single rendering command.

Comment: No shader languages will allow you for more texture slots than 31, it's a hardware limitation. You need to dynamically bind and unbind as you go.